# cassandra primary key conception

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

```
CREATE TABLE c1.ticket (
    uuid int PRIMARY KEY,
    idflycompany int
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

and than

```
 def select(companyId: Int): Future[List[Long]] = {
    val select = QueryBuilder.select()
      .all()
      .from(Connector.KEY_SPACE, table)
      .where(like(idFlyCompany, companyId))

    for {
      resultSet <- session.executeAsync(select)
    } yield {
      resultSet
        .asScala
        .map(row => row.getLong("uuid"))
        .toList
    }
  }
```

Have got:

No supported secondary index found for the non primary key columns restrictions

But in my vision I use ONE PK. 
What is wrong? some misunderstanding of concept ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from this line in your code

> where(like(idFlyCompany, companyId))

what is the method `like()` doing ? Normally you should call `QueryBuilder.eq("column name", value)` to query by primary key

Comment: import QueryBuilder.{eq => like}